# Viewing two different values in ORACLE 10G

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle10g, sqlplus

I have the following statement:

```
SELECT movieID, actorID, title, lastName, firstName, gender 
  FROM Actor, Movie
 WHERE lastName ='Hoffman'
   AND lastName ='Voight';
```

Am trying to obtain information from both these actors through there last name but oracle says no record exists but when I search for them individual there are results for both of them. What i mean is if i do this:

```
SELECT movieID, actorID, title, lastName, firstName, gender 
  FROM Actor, Movie
 WHERE lastName ='Hoffman';
```

and the then run the next one after this has finished:

```
SELECT movieID, actorID, title, lastName, firstName, gender 
  FROM Actor, Movie And lastName 
 WHERE lastName ='Voight';
```

Results for both appear but i require a way where I can search for both these guys from one query.

Comment: Your queries are using ANSI-89 join syntax, but there's no criteria to link the tables so you'll get a cartesian product.  I recommend using ANSI-92 join syntax

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that because you used `AND`, the `lastname` has to be both values... at once.  Which is impossible.  You can switch to using an `OR`:

```
SELECT m.movieID, a.actorID, m.title, a.lastName, a.firstName, a.gender 
  FROM ACTOR a,  
       MOVIE m
 WHERE a.lastName ='Hoffman'
    OR a.lastName ='Voight'
```

Or you can use the `IN` clause:

```
SELECT m.movieID, a.actorID, m.title, a.lastName, a.firstName, a.gender 
  FROM ACTOR a,  
       MOVIE m
 WHERE a.lastName IN ('Hoffman', 'Voight')
```

Logically, `IN` is equivalent to using `OR`.  The `IN` is shorthand so you don't have to write each `OR`.  And `IN` tends to optimize better.  Oracle however limits the number of `IN` clauses -- you'll risk an ORA-01795 error for using more than 1,000.

> what if i want to find a these to actors from 1 movie which is SELECT movieID, actorID, title, lastName, firstName, gender FROM Actor, Movie WHERE lastName ='Hoffman' OR lastName ='Voight' And title ='Midnight Cowboy'; Is this is the correct syntax?

The query provided is syntactically correct, but is not proper syntax for the results you expect.  You need to use brackets/parenthesis, like this:

```
WHERE (lastName ='Hoffman' OR lastName ='Voight') 
  AND title ='Midnight Cowboy'
```

...to properly group the criteria.  It works like order of operations in math...

Comment: what if i want to find a these to actors from 1 movie which is SELECT movieID, actorID, title, lastName, firstName, gender FROM Actor, Movie
WHERE lastName ='Hoffman'
OR lastName ='Voight'
And title ='Midnight Cowboy';

Is this is the correct sytax

Comment: @user1137472: See update -- the parenthesis aren't necessary if you use the `IN` clause.

Comment: SELECT movieID, actorID, title, lastName, firstName, gender FROM Actor, Movie
WHERE (lastName ='Hoffman' OR lastName ='Voight') 
AND title ='Midnight Cowboy';

This is giveing me no rows selected

Comment: @user1137472: There's no join criteria between the tables, fix that first.

Comment: Join how do i do that? i dont know much about joins? but thanks for the answer was helpful will mark it as usful

Comment: @user1137472: There has to be at least one column either table.  IE:  `FROM ACTOR a JOIN MOVIE m ON m.actor_id = a.actor_id`.  There should be a table between the actor & movie table really, to relate more than one actor to a movie.

Comment: so would be like this:

SELECT movieID, actorID, title, lastName, firstName, gender 
FROM Actor JOIN Movie on actor_id =actor_id
WHERE (lastName ='Hoffman' OR lastName ='Voight') 
AND title ='Midnight Cowboy';

Comment: @user1137472: You're missing the `ON` clause -- see my previous comment.  The `ON` clause comes before the `WHERE` clause.

Comment: SELECT movieID, actorID, title, lastName, firstName, gender 
FROM Actor JOIN Movie on actorID = actorID 
WHERE (lastName ='Hoffman' OR lastName ='Voight') AND title ='Midnight Cowboy'; 

This gives no rows selected :(

Comment: @user1137472: Are you sure the data exists?  Make sure you get expected results when not using the JOIN for each table.  I also stress using table aliases, especially when dealing with identical column names in different tables.  Found an issue recently which was compiling (without an alias), that failed once the proper alias was added.

Comment: Yes the records exist but individually they can be located but together can not be fond

Comment: @user1137472: Doesn't make sense -- some detail to this is missing.  If there are actor records, you need to look at why there doesn't appear to be a link to the movie table.  And vice versa.  There's nothing more I can do.

Answer (score 3):

You need `OR`, not `AND`:

```
SELECT movieID, actorID, title, lastName, firstName, gender FROM Actor, Movie
WHERE lastName ='Hoffman'
OR lastName ='Voight';
```

Comment: Thanks will try this an let you know :)

Comment: what if i want to do three fields would i add another "or"